# How to show notification under the bell icon?

Tags: lightning

I want to show users notification on the bell icon on which object I need to create record or which setting i need to turn on ?

[image]

Comment: A Chatter ping to the user will do the trick (a mention in a Chatter post).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly display custom notifications right now. You'll want to vote on [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CORPQA4). As mentioned by David, sending a Chatter Post would suffice, as the user would be notified of the new message, which can include a link to a specific record or other action.

Answer (score 5):

Custom notifications are available in Summer'19 release
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_notificationbuilder.htm