# Show custom Bell Notifications in Salesforce Lightning

Tags: lightning, notification, push-notification, task-notifications

This has been asked about 13 times in this forum already, but the answers seem vague or didn't work for me. So, here it is again. I am looking to show bell notifications in Lightning. Somehow. Be it via a chatter post or by creating a task or via Process Builder. I have tried several avenues but no dice. I am using a Developer Edition, Spring '19 (NOT Communities).

I looked at [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/256989/bell-notifications-via-apex) post and executed below code from Developer Console, no notification. It did create a FeedItem record though.

```
FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
post.ParentId = '00546000002AhVY'; //This is a different System Admin Id
post.Body = 'This is body.';
post.Title = 'This is Title';
post.LinkUrl = '/lightning/r/acres__ABC__c/a054600000DnQW2AAN/view?0.source=alohaHeader';
insert post;
```

[This article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=livemessage_automatic_message_notifications_process.htm&type=5) in 8.a. suggests *In the Action Type menu, select Messaging Notifications.* I don't see that option at all in Process Builder.  I do see 'Post to Chatter' Action Type which didn't seem to do the trick either.

[Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/224151/how-to-show-notification-under-the-bell-icon), @sfdcfox answered that 'custom' notifications are not possible.

[The accepted answer here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/233400/how-to-create-notifications-in-salesforce-lightning-via-process-builder) is a straight copy-paste from Salesforce Documentation around notifications for Tasks, but just feels incomplete/vague. It address how to add 'Reminder Set' field to Task layout, but not much about notifications itself.

I then tried a standard InvocableAction via workbench by posting below input to this endpoint without luck: /services/data/v45.0/actions/standard/chatterPost

```
{ "inputs" :
  [
  {
    "subjectNameOrId" : "sysadmin@company.com",
    "type" : "user",
    "text" : "first chatter post!"
  },
  {
    "subjectNameOrId" : "someone@company.com",
    "type" : "user",
    "text" : "second chatter post!"
  }
  ]
}
```

**Can someone, please, provide clear step-by-step (tested to be working) instructions on how to show bell notifications in Lightning UI? Could there be a setting I am missing?**

> My use-case

When a date field on a particular record is empty, I would like to send a bell notification to a user identified via another field on the same record: 'Hey *User*, this date field has been cleared. You are free to make your changes now.'

Comment: If you don't mind waiting a month, there is a solution coming in the Summer' 19 release.

https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_flow_notificationbuilder.htm